# What is the specific meaning of "Smoking crater?"

Tags: meaning, expressions, metaphors

I'm suddenly seeing and hearing the phrase "smoking crater." I've noticed it mostly from sportswriters and commentators, usually in reference to a coach leaving a college team in bad shape, or an underperforming player being traded. It's always used in a derogatory fashion, but what's the specific meaning?

Comment: It's a crater that's emitting smoke, presumably from the (very recent) impact that created it.  I expect that the implication is that the person or thing being likened to a smoking crater has just been (metaphorically) destroyed.

Comment: I've noticed it mostly from sportswriters and commentators, usually in reference to a coach leaving a college team in bad shape, or an underperforming player being traded.

Answer (score 1):

The literal meaning of a "smoking crater" is pretty simple.

[A crater](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/crater) is a hole in the ground, created by an explosion or impact.

The smoke implies that whatever created the hole, did so only just recently, since its remnants continue to burn.

To "turn something into a smoking crater" is to completely destroy it with explosives, so that the smoking crater is all that is left behind.

The phrase can be used metaphorically, to refer to non-physical destruction that is just as thorough and dramatic as an explosion. From the first page of google results for "smoking crater", I see [a relationship breaking up](http://www.thetanknyc.org/storytelling/445-smoking-crater/) and [a business failure](https://www.greentechmedia.com/articles/read/NovaSolar-the-former-OptiSolar-Leaving-Smoking-Crater-in-Fremont) both described as leaving smoking craters.